# Getting form_tag ids for Javascript Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure my title was hugely unhelpeful, I'll try and describe my problem better here. Essentially, I have a bunch of form tags, actually I'm using formtastic, so they look kinda like this:

```
  <%= f.inputs :email, :pass, :passconf, :for => :register_attributes %>
```

These generate a group of input fields and labels with rather long id names, e.g. one such field is called `'posting_register_attributes_email`'.

Now, I'd like to create a link that hides/shows these elements on request. It's easy to do brute force, e.g.:

```
<%= link_to_function "Register", "$('#posting_register_attributes_email').hide()" %>
```

But I feel surely there must be a more elegant way of doing it than typing out the full generated name, is there a helper that will let me doing something like `[:register_attributes][:email].hide` or something to make this less tedious? I feel like there must be.

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually a rather silly question of me, since I can just hide the whole div instead of hiding everything individually, but I would like to know if there's a helper to get those long id names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[id*='register_attributes']").hide();
```